Can't I insert an element at the start of array with a chained method without using map?
I have a chain of methods that treat an array. Then I was trying to do a simple thing: add an element at the start of the array in a method chain. Initially I tried:


console.log(
    [1, 2, 3]
        .map(a=>a+1)
        .splice(0, 0, 7)
        .map(a=>a*10)
)



I used splice, because unshift returns the number of elements in the array. So hoped the result would be [70, 20, 30, 40], but the result was [] as splice returns the elements deleted in the array.
I give it a thought and couldn't find any other way to do this. Not even with .apply.
That's a simple thing I can easily solve by breaking the chain, but I thought it might be an oportunity to learn a bit (and don't like to give up that easily :D), so searching a bit I found only one way to chain this:


console.log(
    [2, 3, 4]
        .map(a=>a+1)
        .concat(7)
        .map((e, i, a) => i == 0 ? a[a.length - 1] : a[i-1])
        .map(a=>a*10)
)



I mean... really ? there should be a better way to chain a simple insert at first position. Anyone knows a better way ?

There's no definite answer to this because . cannot be generally assumed to be usable for "chaining" -- there's no effective contract that requires methods of Array to return an array, and splice is the example to prove the opposite. There was a proposal to add a "pipe" operator but it didn't make it into the language. I think you'll find the proposal to be a very useful read. As last resort, nothing prevents you from applying a bit of functional programming and impement what you need with the reduce method.

OP can use .toSpliced to achieve the desired behaviour. Note that .toSpliced is non mutating.

@Palladium02 yes, toSpliced() is the answer. But I checked the compatibility and it's too new. It was added to browser versions and node around 1 year ago. Better not to use it yet.

@ArmenMichaeli now you mentioned it, I found that .reduce((a, v)=>a.concat(v), [7]) does the job. Can you think in a better reduce ?

Based on my added answer, now I'm on a dilemma on what answer to accept. I'll think I'll wait a couple of days and accept the most voted answer. If someone want to say something about what answer to accept, please be my guest.


I used splice, because unshift returns the number of elements in the array. So hoped the result would be [70, 20, 30, 40], but the result was [] as splice returns the elements deleted in the array.

You're looking for the new toSpliced method which returns a new array with the modification applied (instead of mutating the receiver and returning the deleted elements):


console.log(
    [1, 2, 3]
        .map(a=>a+1)
        .toSpliced(0, 0, 7)
        .map(a=>a*10)
)



Of course there's various alternatives to achieve what you want, like .reverse().concat([7]).reverse(), but they're not very readable.

Based on the answers and comments, as I think that toSpliced() method is too new. I think I decided myself by:


console.log(
    [2, 3, 4]
        .map(a=>a+1)
        .reduce((a, v)=>(a.push(v), a), [7])
        .map(a=>a*10)
)



There is also the slow but more readable option below.


console.log(
    [2, 3, 4]
        .map(a=>a+1)
        .reduce((a, v)=>a.concat(v), [7])
        .map(a=>a*10)
)



Obviously toSpliced() method as @Palladium02 and @Bergi noted is far more readable and @AlexanderNenashev's answer the fastest by far. So depending on your need (readability, compatibility, speed or best of both worlds) you may choose any of the answers above.

For the record, this may also be [2, 3, 4].map(a => a + 1).reduce((a, v) => a.concat(v * 10), [7].map(v => v * 10)) (which also offers the ability to insert more than one elements into the original Array). Furthermore when the Array is not huge, I don't think performance is a real issue here.

"I think that toSpliced() method is too new" - then add a polyfill for it to your page :-)

I would suggest to avoid chaining and thus avoid intermediate arrays (Array#reduce() is a king):


const map = n => (n+1)*10;
console.log(
    [1, 2, 3].reduce((r, n, i) => (i ? r.push(map(n)) : r.push(7*10, map(n)), r), [])
)



And benchmarking:
` Chrome/125
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                         n=3        |       n=30       |       n=300       |      n=3000     
Array#reduce()      ■ 1.00x x10m 197 | ■ 1.00x x10m 866 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 788 | ■ 1.00x x10k 111
Array#toSpliced()     8.48x  x1m 167 |  10.53x  x1m 912 |  10.63x x100k 838 |   6.07x x10k 674
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const $chunk = [1,2,3];
const $input = [], arr = $input;

// @benchmark Array#reduce()
const map = n => (n+1)*10;
arr.reduce((r, n, i) => (i ? r.push(map(n)) : r.push(7*10, map(n)), r), [])

// @benchmark Array#toSpliced()
arr.map(a=>a+1)
        .toSpliced(0, 0, 7)
        .map(a=>a*10)
        
/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




That's not exactly method chaining.

@Bergi exactly, just to suggest some alternative...

@AlexanderNenashev nice one, but did you read my comment in the question ? What you think of .reduce((a, v)=>a.concat(v), [7]) ?

Forget it. Though more readable, it's the slowest. And by A LOT:
Open in the playground

This is much better: .reduce((a, v)=>(a.push(v), a), [7]). Check it out:
https://silentmantra.github.io/benchmark#H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VR0U7DMAz8FWsgLRlRwuBh0qaNIX4AicdtDyENpKxzKzetQIh%2Fx6Ht4IFJUKVqdb7z%2BZz3kSszP5rzB%2BsI5y40uIclbKbqSl3vFlvsCzlWTUyFnQJLxH8dxIwtGgPrR48uHCzt4ZbIvp2RzxrnhRw6HGzFIoTlCgReTOVkeslabqV7piAFqCCXX5QcboB01dRBsFKglDAfgBlrFfSwAuJ3s5OnBonlQ1XkzmdpluSXhHa5sjzEFqF%2F9DeNe%2FOZ%2FSwOEjY%2B6dPFuCvR2fir1TGoVdBKRrXryG0KMEsJ%2FmF0nzbxFxthu60lF3vKaUjKjpN1vc%2BriYEnH10Q4xBjVc%2BNcRnqlzrzRd6SRh%2FNczB1XniMB4uRrDnOaYrSZp6YPZY6Bo%2BC0p2Sjv6VV9NBvrWFlIvRxyc7WfzqgwIAAA%3D%3D

@NelsonTeixeira looks the best if you need chaining

Frankly, this -- e.g. a single reduce call -- might be the preferred way to do it for one single specific use case. Which assumes you are not implementing a e.g. general mechanism for "pivoting" and otherwise working with arrays. For a general approach "chaining" is better, I'd say -- so you can augment chains with different methods or functions. Each function takes an array and returns an array, promising not to mutate input (as a general precaution).

@ArmenMichaeli i think for the most cases of chaining there's always Array#reduce alternative

In light of the comments on your question and also taking into account the other proposals here, I think you ought to simply "polyfill" the
toSpliced method and pretend it was always there.
Here's a working implementation of the method:
Array.prototype.toSpliced ??= function(...args) {
    const copy = Array.from(this);
    copy.splice(...args);
    return copy;
}

Now you can just use toSpliced whether it is provided by the platform or added with the above. Firefox, for example, implemented toSpliced some 11 months ago. When platform support becomes broad enough for your application, the above can simply be removed as "dead code".
At any rate, toSpliced allows you to "chain" your operations like you wanted to, something at least one other answer already recommends you do:
[2, 3, 4]
    .map(a => a + 1)
    .toSpliced(0, 0, 7)
    .map(a => a * 10)

To give you some rationale for my proposing of a solution relying on so-called polyfilling: the toSpliced method has been specified by a standards body and most of the usual suspects have already implemented it, so there's, in a sense, no going back. Normally -- some features are removed down the timeline, but it's far and in between and it takes a long time anyway. Point being, I think we can agree toSpliced is here to stay. Knowing that, you might as well depend on it -- except that you can't if the platform hasn't implemented it. That's where polyfilling comes in, allowing you not to change your application code, but just ad-hoc plug in the support you need.
A note on overhead of immutable data structures / functional approach / overhead of copying data
I don't know your application but generally don't worry about performance, is my advice to you. If you know enough to use the map-reduce paradigm, I bet your code isn't slow enough to matter. Unless you're in the 1% of use cases where every millisecond counts, which isn't as common as some would have you believe. Code is written once and read many times -- it's more important for it to communicate intent, so in general you'd be on the right side of right when writing readable code. The average modern JavaScript machine is simultaneously very fast and very slow -- it's fast enough to let you implement a bunch of scripts that won't slow down your page, if done correctly (with copying of arrays, in general), and slow enough for you not to gain much by re-factoring your chain(s) into imperative loop-based race-car analogue that modifies arrays in place to your liking (and you might introduce errors). Generally, that is. Just heed the "premature optimization is evil" saying -- put your chain behind a method call, and if, when profiled, it's too slow, replace the body of the method with whatever funky loop you can conjure that speeds it all up 100x or whatever.

Some answers should be allowed to be voted more than once. This is one of them. Excellent analysis. Thanks.

That polyfill doesn't work

@Bergi can you show the problems or one that works ? I've seen that polyfill mentioned in some articles, like this one and this one.

[1, 2, 3].toSpliced(0, 0, 7) should return [7, 1, 2, 3], yours returns []. Looks like one of those articles copied the bad code from the other.

@Bergi, it's not any copied code, I wrote it for this answer, although I admit to not have tested it.

The polyfill as written prior was indeed faulty, since splice doesn't return the result in the first place, but I have now corrected (and tested) the variant I amended in the answer.
